# Adding an angled ribbon to a card

Tags: css

All of the tutorials that I find online explain how to create a `ribbon` that is angled 45% degrees in the corner of a `div`. (or other variations)

What I would like to achieve is to place a ribbon under any angle that I wish, for example 15 degrees angle. My latest attempt is: https://jsfiddle.net/8vjL3has/9/

```css
.main {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 50px;

  position: relative;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.ribbon-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0px;
  right: -0px;
}


.ribbon-red {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 0;
  background-color: #ea181e;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
      <div class="main">
        <div class="ribbon-wrapper">
          <div class="ribbon-red">
          <span>label</span>
          <span>second line</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

But I cannot get the angled position to work correctly. The label should always be positioned in the top-right corner and then grow depending on the text size.

Expected results are for the text with 2 lines

[image]

For the text with 1 line

[image]

(made in Paint)

The width of the main element (card) is responsive (can be resized horizontally), so if the size of the card is changed I expect the ribbon to change it's size accordingly.. Is this possible to achieve with CSS, or should I just place some absolute images on top? Can't figure it out..

Comment: +1 for using Paint™ (and presenting pretty much almost all the necessary). Not sure about the height growing with text, since in your case the text should be encased in an irregular trapezoid (asymmetric) containment space - and you did not explained that crucial part.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the (say) first word of the text is very long? You have shown the ribbon always starting a set amount down on the right hand side, but this may not leave enough space for the first word - so are there some constraints you can put onto the ribbon positioning (especially for narrow viewports)?